# Validate a list of objects with Oval Xml configurations

Tags: java, xml, spring, xpath, oval

I need to validate the objects of list with Xml configurations.
User contains a list of bags.

```
class User{
private List<Bag> bags = new ArrayList<Bag>();
}
```

Can't i use instanceOf element within the  element to validate the all the Bag properties. Bag has properties like, name, color, etc. I need to validate this while calling Validator.validate(user);

I saw an example with overriding isSatisfied method. But It uses annotaions. I think this can be done with the xml configurations itself.

Greatly appreciate your help.